# How to access parent page methods from usercontrol Button in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am designing a dash board which contains Pods and pod containers and every pod container can have multiple pods.and every pods can have multiple user controls.
In one of my pods i have a usercontrol which bears a back button.Once i click it means i need to hide the existing pod and have to show some other pod.For that i have hardcoded some method in MainPage.xaml.
So can you just suggest me how to invoke that method in parent page from usecontrol which has back button.
Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

First, think if you can find another design with better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Who should be responsible for closing a pod? And showing a new one?

Then, if you still need this kind of communication, try with an event. When the button is pressed, you could raise a `Close` event, which would be handled by the pod.